# best way to select...where in using linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

There are three tables in the database that are relevant.  Advocate, Vendor, and Advocate_Vendor.

The Advocate_Vendor table being the many to many link, has a vendorId and an advocateId.

My end goal is to get back a `List<Advocate>` object...a collection of advocates that belong to one Vendor.  I wrote this:

```
var list = new List<Advocate>();

        foreach (var vendorAdvocates in db.Advocate_Vendors)
        {
            if (vendorAdvocates.VendorId == vendorId)
            {
                list.Add(db.Advocates.SingleOrDefault(a => a.AdvocateId == vendorAdvocates.AdvocateId));
            }
        }
```

And then this:

```
var list = (from vendorAdvocates in db.Advocate_Vendors 
            where vendorAdvocates.VendorId == vendorId 
            select db.Advocates.SingleOrDefault(a => 
                a.AdvocateId == vendorAdvocates.AdvocateId)).ToList();
```

Is this the best way?  Seems wrong, like maybe there could be a more streamlined way to do this using a 'contains' keyword or something that looks a bit more readable...get all the vendor's advocates

thanks

Comment: Avoid the `Contains`, it's slow.

Comment: You should navigation properties defined in your model, and they are exactly to do that thing for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `join` between Advocate_Vendors and Advocates would be the right way of doing it.

```
var list = (from vendorAdvocates in db.Advocate_Vendors 
            join advocates in db.Advocates
               on vendorAdvocates.AdvocateId equals advocates.AdvocateId
            where vendorAdvocates.VendorId == vendorId
            select advocates).ToList();
```

Comment: @Magnus: Does entity framework generate a different query for my answer and your answer? Just curious.

Comment: @mynkow The queries will look different, yours with `cross join` and mine with `inner join`, but the execution plan will the same. (inner join)

Comment: This solution produces no records for Advocate_Vendors which have no corresponding advocates.  That's technically a difference from the original implementation.

Comment: @recursive From reading the question "to get a collection of advocates that belong to one Vendor", I don't think the op wants a `left join`.

Comment: @Magnus: NHibernate works exactly the opposite :). Good to know that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = (from vendorAdvocates in db.Advocate_Vendors
            from advocate in db.Advocates
            where vendorAdvocates.VendorId == vendorId && 
                  vendorAdvocates.AdvocateId = advocate.Id
            select advocate)
           .ToList();
```

Comment: This is not quite the same. If a given advocate vendor doesn't have a matching advocate, this method will not insert a corresponding null in the result list.  I'm not sure if that's an important part of the original query, but it appears to have been done intentionally, so it's worth noting.

Comment: yes it will be possible for a vendor to have zero advocates, thanks for the note

Comment: Insert? This is only select!

Comment: Yes, this is a select, but it produces a `List<>`.  My use of the word "insert" refers to the population of that result list.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up your foreign keys and navigation properties properly, it should be possible to write this way, or something like it:

```
var list = (from vendorAdvocates in db.Advocate_Vendors 
            where vendorAdvocates.VendorId == vendorId 
            select db.Advocate).ToList();
```